# CSS Outline not showing for div in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, outline

I have a div with outline set using jQuery. It's working fine in Chrome but not working in IE.

I know outline does not work in IE6 and IE7, but it's also not working in IE8 and IE9.

I have a div FormContainer in which other div's are placed when i click on a particular div I want to get it highlighted so on click I set focus of that div and handling focus event like this:

```
$('.FormContainer div').focus(function (e) {    
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('QuestionText') == false) {    
            $(this).css({ 'outline': 'black auto thin' });
            $(this).find('.buttonControl').show();    
            $(this).find('.buttonControl').css({ 'border': '1px solid black', 'border-bottom': 'none' });    
            $(this).addClass('FocusDiv');    
        }    
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();    
    });
```

All other css is working fine, but only `$(this).css({ 'outline': 'black auto thin' });` is not working out. It's working fine in Chrome but can't get it work in IE8 and IE9.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you edit your question and add the relevant code your using, and be more specific about the problem? That way we can help you a lot more/better/easier. Note that you can edit your question at any time to improve it and add details.

Comment: sorry for short description now i have added code which i am using please help me out

Comment: Ah yes, much better! I see you got an answer now too, keep it up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in IE8:

```
$('div').css({'outline': '1px solid blue'});​
```

You can test it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/MCPHX/1/

**Update**
The part that IE doesn't like is "auto" within the value for outline. So use `black solid thin` instead.

BTW, this is shorthand for `{'outline-width': 'thin', 'outline-style': 'solid', 'outline-color': 'black'}`

Standard accepted values for these properties can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp

Comment: i have edited my question please have a look at it